# Facebook login button not visible

Tags: php, facebook

I've taken the facebook login button example from facebook's official example [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login).
This is the code (without any change).

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '385937518116668',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
</body>
```

When running this example as is, everything works fine.
However, once I remove the html, head and body I can't see the facebook login button.
All I see is the "Login with facebook" text.
The reason I want to remove these tags is since the page is included in another php file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: When it's included it will just be added in between them, so your not REALLY removing them. It will work fine if you go to the including page, and not the login page directly.

Comment: I've tried both calling the main page which includes the login page and calling only the login page (without the html/body tags) but none worked.

Comment: First entry in the bug tracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/256345417806493

Comment: Have you tried looking for javascript errors on the main page?

Comment: @Igy: Last comments are from the last hours, maybe I'm expected to see it working soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

facebookLogin.html.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include 'fblogin.html';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the contents of the fblogin.html file are:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '385937518116668',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
```

Comment: Well, that's really weird. Suddenly my code works fine. Maybe it is related to the bug Igy was mentioning above. I saw that people were reporting things getting back to work in the last hours. Thanks.